# XMLHttpRequest() does not work in the latest versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox-addon, browser-addons

In my addons I always used new XMLHttpRequest () and it worked perfectly.
Now all requests ajax stopped working.

Currently new XMLHttpRequest () is causing the following error: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

So I changed my code to:

```
try {
    var XMLHttpRequest;
    if (typeof(XMLHttpRequest) == "undefined")
        XMLHttpRequest = content.XMLHttpRequest;
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
...
```

Sometimes the request usually works, but sometimes not.

The code "alert(e);" is never executed, then there is no error there.

I can not understand why sometimes it works and sometimes not.
Previously I used only *var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();* and always worked.

Now how do I create a new ajax request?

Comment: Yes, of *course* XHR works.  Q: What does your (failing) code look like *before* you put in "var XMLHttpRequest"?  Q: are you doing anything different from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=XMLHttpRequest)?  Q: What version of Firefox is failing on you?  What version last worked for you?

Comment: PS: I would *not* name your variable "XMLHttpRequest" ;)  Try "xhr", or something like that ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 - You may want to put that as an answer.

Comment: @paulsm4 I was just using xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); before and it worked perfectly.
But now with the Firefox 15.0 does not work.

Comment: @paulsm4 When I was using simply var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();, an error occurred: "ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined".
So I tried to fix the problem of XMLHttpRequest does not exist creating a variable with the same name.

Comment: @ClaudioHenriquedaSilva: You say that this isn't the Add-on SDK. What context does this code run in? Script loaded from an overlay? JavaScript module? XPCOM component? Btw, `var XMLHttpRequest` will make sure that `XMLHttpRequest` is undefined - you should indeed name that variable differently.

Comment: @WladimirPalant The script is being loaded from a overlay (through the .xul file). Again: "var XMLHttpRequest" was just an attempt to fix the problem that XMLHttpRequest is undefined.

Comment: @ClaudioHenriquedaSilva: Well, works for me in Firefox 15 and Firefox 18.0a1 - `XMLHttpRequest` is definitely defined in the context of the browser window. Unless some extension did `var XMLHttpRequest` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, when you are running in the context of a browser window (like code loaded by an overlay to that window) then `XMLHttpRequest` should definitely be available. I verified that just in case and it works for me.

But in case everything else fails you can still instantiate the XPCOM component corresponding to XMLHttpRequest directly:

```js
var xmlhttp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIXMLHttpRequest);
xmlhttp.open(...);
```

Comment: Thank you.

I'll try to find what was causing XMLHttpRequest stay unavailable.
But if I do not find it, I will follow your advice and instantiate the XPCOM component corresponding to XMLHttpRequest directly.